# Java сompare array values ​and find the nearest

Tags: java, arrays, double

My problem:
There are two arrays

`double [] a = {0.5, 0.6, 0.3};
 double [] b = {0.2, 0.1, 0.9};`

And i have some third array : `double [] c = {0.1, 0.2, 0.8}`.
As we saw, separately elements of this array are nearest to the second array -> 0.2-0.1 < 0.5-0.1 (b[0]-c[0] < a[0]-c[0]).

in other words, I must find the nearest array from other arrays.

So, how can I determine this in code?

Comment: what if b[0]-c[0]=a[1]-c[1]

Comment: it is excluded in this case

Comment: So you are trying to find which array has values that are closer to `c`? And `a` is closer to  `c` than `b` is if and only if for all valid `x`, `abs(a[x] - c[x]) < abs(b[x] - c[x])`. Is that the criteria?

Comment: So, in a list of arrays, you must find the array that when diffed with all other arrays yields the smallest sum? Is there always only 3 arrays?

Comment: Smallest sum of absolute differences? Smallest square root of the sum of squares (Euclidean distance if you think of your arrays as points in a 3D vector space)? Largest number of dimensions in which the absolute value of the distance is smaller? You need to define precisely what you mean by "nearest" before making any attempt to code it.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to find the nearest array  by absolute value,you can use math.abs() method to get and compare them.

```
public static double[] nearestArray(double[] a,double[] b,double[] c){
    double an=0,bn=0;
    for(int i =0;i<c.length;i++){
        an=an+Math.abs(a[i]-c[i]);
        bn=bn+Math.abs(b[i]-c[i]);
    }
    if(an>bn){
        return b;
    }else if(bn>an){
        return a;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

but if you want to find the the closest array on linear programming,you can processing data on matlab or python.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i solve my problem by another way))